# Why does the first await gets ignores?

Tags: javascript

I wanted to change the body background color to red first, and then to blue. But it's skipping the red. Got it from Colt Steele's The Web Developer Bootcamp.

```js
function changeBG(color, delay) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
  }, delay);
}

async function init() {
  await changeBG('red', 1000);
  await changeBG('blue', 1000);
}

init();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `changeBG()` doesn't return a promise so `await` is useless

Comment: Your function doesn’t return a promise to await.

Comment: Please [search thoroughly](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+await+not+waiting) before posting. More about searching [here](/help/searching). There are dozens of questions asking why `await` isn't waiting, with dozens of answers saying (roughly) "because you're using `await` on something that isn't a promise."

Answer (score 4):

You're not returning `Promise` from `changeBG`. The following will work :-

```js
function changeBG(color, delay) {
return new Promise(resolve=>{
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
    resolve();
  }, delay);
})

}

async function init() {
  await changeBG('red', 1000);
  await changeBG('blue', 1000);
}

init();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to return Promise to use async and await.

```js
function changeBG(color, delay) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
      resolve();
    }, delay);
  })
}

async function init() {
  await changeBG('red', 1000);
  await changeBG('blue', 1000);
}

init();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```